# Virus/Malware etc. | Is reading with .fs same like executing the file?

Tags: node.js, fs, virus

Imagine you have a sample.txt(or every other file format that is readable with .fs to get the text data) and this text file has a virus/malware in it.

When you execute the file you will get the virus.

But what happen if you would read the sample.txt with the fs module from node.js and then re-export just the readed text data?
Does the virus will be aswell execute with just reading it via fs? Or is fs basicly executing sample.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a file does not execute it.
It does not matter if it could be executed or not, reading simply does not consider execution at all.